# Robo Script is not working for Robo Test in Firebase Test Lab

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I uploaded APK on **Test Lab** and the JSON script (generated with Robo Script Recorder inside Android Studio), yet the Robo test works randomly like Robo script has no effect at all. Please guide me if i am skipping something important. There isn't much community support out there yet, as Robo Script was just introduced in december,2017. I have done several iterations. Here is the JSON script generated by Robo Script Recorder.

Please guide me if you had any successful experience with **Robo Script**

```html
[
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED",
    "timestamp": 1519108428358,
    "replacementText": "Version  2.0.1 - stg",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "android.widget.TextView",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 2,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_activity_login_app_version",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": "Version"
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.RelativeLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 3,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_activity_login_layout_bottom_bar",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.RelativeLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/login_layout_background",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED",
    "timestamp": 1519108430125,
    "replacementText": "20-FEB-2018 11:34 AM",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "android.widget.TextView",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 3,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_activity_login_build_date",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.RelativeLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 3,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_activity_login_layout_bottom_bar",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.RelativeLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/login_layout_background",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
    "timestamp": 1519108437083,
    "replacementText": "",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "android.widget.EditText",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_activity_login_username",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.RelativeLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_activity_login_form",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_activity_login_controls",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED",
    "timestamp": 1519108438911,
    "replacementText": "j@45.com",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "android.widget.EditText",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_activity_login_username",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.RelativeLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_activity_login_form",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_activity_login_controls",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED",
    "timestamp": 1519108457605,
    "replacementText": "8240",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "android.widget.EditText",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 5,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_activity_login_password",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.RelativeLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_activity_login_form",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_activity_login_controls",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
    "timestamp": 1519108468385,
    "replacementText": "LOGIN",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "android.widget.Button",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 2,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_activity_login_btn",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": "LOGIN"
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.RelativeLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/login_layout_background",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.FrameLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
        "resourceId": "android:id/content",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
    "timestamp": 1519108473787,
    "replacementText": "Accept",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "android.widget.Button",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_inapp_license_view_accept_btn",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": "Accept"
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 3,
        "resourceId": "",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.RelativeLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "timestamp": 1519108492539,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 10000,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
    "timestamp": 1519108502208,
    "replacementText": "",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "android.widget.FrameLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 2,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/tabsLayout",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.TabWidget",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 2,
        "resourceId": "android:id/tabs",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
    "timestamp": 1519108507006,
    "replacementText": "Package",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "android.widget.Button",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 2,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/view_courses",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": "Package"
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.TableRow",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/view_switcher",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.TableLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/AudioVideoHeader",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "timestamp": 1519108511679,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 10000,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
    "timestamp": 1519108512263,
    "replacementText": "",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": 0,
        "groupViewChildPosition": -1,
        "resourceId": "",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.ListView",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/gift_given_users_list",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 2,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/send_gift_list_view_container",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "timestamp": 1519108514916,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 10000,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
    "timestamp": 1519108516244,
    "replacementText": "",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "android.widget.ImageButton",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 3,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_course_detail_fragment_downloading_bt",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.RelativeLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_course_detail_header_info_container",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.RelativeLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
    "timestamp": 1519108528267,
    "replacementText": "",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "android.widget.ImageButton",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 3,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_course_detail_fragment_downloading_bt",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.RelativeLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_course_detail_header_info_container",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.RelativeLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "timestamp": 1519108529946,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 300,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
    "timestamp": 1519108534032,
    "replacementText": "",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_downloading_row_inprgoress_btn_pause",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_downloading_row_cancel_btn_holder",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.RelativeLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_downloading_row_btn_holder",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "timestamp": 1519108535675,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 300,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
    "timestamp": 1519108537244,
    "replacementText": "",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_downloading_row_inprgoress_btn_pause",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.LinearLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_downloading_row_cancel_btn_holder",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.RelativeLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
        "resourceId": "com.directsalesmobile.connect21:id/ui_downloading_row_btn_holder",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "timestamp": 1519108538787,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 300,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: The script should run, then after that, Robo will continue its crawl as normal.  The purpose of the script is to bypass screens that require specific input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Robo script and the way you uploaded it to Test Lab look OK. Robo performs actions from the script until the first one that fails, at which point it resumes a regular crawl. To see how many actions from Robo script were performed successfully, you can search for "Robo script" string in the logcat file produced by the crawl. Alternatively, you can wait a few days and re-run your Robo test - at that point, the Robo script status should show up directly in the crawl video.

Another sanity check is to record the same actions as you did for the Robo script but using Run -> Record Espresso Test and see if the generated test passes locally.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Checking the logs was really useful and i already tried Espresso recorder and it failed giving errors related to finding resources in xml against IDs issue seems to be related to multiple application IDs for different build flavors, since project is quite big having 5 build flavors and 6 build variants. I will be spending some time in properly overriding the package contents in respective packages. This probably is the most sane solution so i'm accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way to test Robo Scripts locally-

1. You need to setup App Crawler.
2. Then, invoke App Crawler launcher using following command

   > java -jar crawl_launcher.jar --robo-script-file < robo-script-path>
   >   --apk-file < apk-path> --android-sdk < android-sdk-path>

Note: Here, we are adding path to robo script using

> —- robo-script-file < robo-script-path>

You can read more about this here: [Test Robo Scripts Locally: Useful For Firebase Test Lab & Pre-launch Reports](https://android.jlelse.eu/test-robo-scripts-locally-useful-for-firebase-test-lab-pre-launch-reports-41da83d5769f)

Answer (score 0):

Do check the build variant of the apk where you're getting your automated tests from i.e. creating test from debug variant will not work in release variant.